# Core Data, duplicate and deleted RSS entries

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, rss

I've been working on an RSS Reader, using core data for caching. Like a lot of people, I wanted to avoid duplicate entries, which led me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185885/prevent-duplicates-when-importing-rss-feed-to-core-data) question, and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656244/how-to-prevent-core-data-making-duplicates-in-ios-5/10344505#10344505).
But, there was another thing I wanted, I also wanted to give users the ability to delete articles, and avoid adding deleted articles again when refreshing a feed, that is if the deleted article still existed in the feed. So, my solution currently, is, to maintain another entity in my managed object context with unique identifiers (which how I identify each item in the feed) of deleted articles, I just add the identifier of the article that is being deleted to that entity, and check against it.

Now, here is a piece of code that I wrote to accomplish all of the above. This code is run every time a new item in the feed is parsed, during the parsing process.

```
    dispatch_queue_t checkQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.feedreader.backgroundchecking", NULL);

    dispatch_async(checkQueue,^{
        NSMutableArray *mutablesortedArticles = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.feeds.sortedArticles];

        if (!mutablesortedArticles) {
            // Handle the error.
        }

        if ([[mutablesortedArticles valueForKey:@"identifier"]
             containsObject:article.identifier]) {
            NSLog(@"This article already exists");
            return;
        }else {
            NSMutableArray *mutabledeletedArticles = [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.alldeletedArticles];

            if (!mutabledeletedArticles) {
                // Handle the error.
            }

            if ([mutabledeletedArticles valueForKey:@"identifier"]
                 containsObject:article.identifier]) {
                NSLog(@"This article has been deleted");
                return;
            }else {
                Article *newArticle = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Article" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

                newArticle.title = article.title;
                newArticle.date = article.date;
                newArticle.link = article.link;
                newArticle.summary = article.summary;
                newArticle.image = article.image;
                newArticle.identifier = article.identifier;
                newArticle.updated = article.updated;
                newArticle.content = article.content;
                newArticle.feed = self.feed;

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
                    NSError *error = nil;
                    [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
                    if (error) {
                        NSLog(@"%@", error);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Both, self.feeds.sortedArticles and self.alldeletedArticles are fetched from managed object context before parsing starts.

My problem begins when this code is being run, the UI freezes, for 1-2 seconds (I tried it with a feed that had a little more than 500 articles in the managed object context). So, I guess my question is, is there a more efficient way to do what I'm trying to do here, one that hopefully doesn't freeze the UI?
Perhaps a better way of dealing with deleted articles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first suggestion would be to handle deleted articles by added a "itemDeleted" property to the *Article* entity. Then you have only one list of objects to check when inserting new items.

(*Hint:* Don't call that attribute "deleted". `isDeleted` is a built-in property of `NSManagedObject`, so that is likely to cause name collisions.)

The next suggestion is to save the managed object context only after *all* items have been imported, and not after each each item (**EDIT:** See also Caffeine's answer, which was posted while I was writing this.)

Finally, searching each new item in the list of all articles separately is a pattern that does not scale well. [Implementing Find-or-Create Efficiently](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003174-SW4) in the "Core Data Programming Guide" describes a pattern that might be better:

- for a list of to-be-inserted items, perform a fetch request that fetches all items of this list which are already present in the database,
- traverse both the list of new items and the fetched list in parallel, to find out which items are really new and have to be inserted.

Comment: +1 good suggestion to use *find or create pattern*. But I didn't see a context for the background thread @SamJ Each thread needs to create its own context. You can share objects among threads by means of their `NSManagedObjectID`.

Comment: @flexaddicted I'm not actually doing anything with managed object context in the background thread. The only thing I do in the background thread is check already existing arrays (previously fetched from the managed object context on the main thread) for exiting & deleted articles, and create a new entry, which I save to the managed object context on the main thread. The purpose of the background thread, it to, well, avoid freezing the UI.

Comment: @SamJ.: flexaddicted is right: You call `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` in the background thread. But all Core Data operations must be done on the thread/queue associated with the context.

Comment: @SamJ. you are creating objects in the back thread. And you are using a context that comes from somewhere. Am I wrong?

Comment: @SamJ. So my suggestion is creating a thread/queue context and use this to save in background. If you take this approach you should share the persistent coordinator. In other words, you need to set the persistent coordinator used in the main context to the back one. I think the delay you have is due to this problem.

Comment: @Martin R: Thanks, I see what you mean.

Comment: @MartinR: I do have a few concerns about your suggesstions. You suggested adding an "itemDeleted" property to the Article entity instead having deleted articles in a seperate entity. My only concern with this approach would be disk space usage, since the enrty isnt actually deleted just essentially marked as deleted. Plus that would mean adding another predicate to my fetch request when I want to display the articles in a tableview. Do you think that'd be a good/efficient idea?

Comment: My second question is about your second suggestion. You suggested to save the managed object context only after all items have been imported. Though I do intend to try this approach out before coming to any conclusions, my concern with this one is that, I see the UI freeze, even when save is never called on the managed object context, that is all articles in the parsed feed either already exist or have been deleted.

Comment: @SamJ.: 1) I suggested the "itemDeleted" property because it would improve the speed of insertion as you have to check only against one list instead of two. You are right that this implies more disk usage (you can clear all other attributes, so that it is mainly the storage of one table row with the "identifier"). I wouldn't bother about the fetch request, this is done on the SQLite level and is normally very fast. - This are only suggestions, you have to test the performance yourself (or profile with Instruments) to find the bootlicks. - (to be continued ...)

Comment: @SamJ.: ... 2) I do not fully understand your comment. You have two options. (A) as suggested by Caffeine in his answer: Use a nested child context for importing the data. The "save" operation on the child context merges the changes one level up to the main context. (B) as suggested by flexaddicted: Use a separate background context to import the data and then save. The main context would then register for save notifications and merge the data. - Both methods should work without UI freezes.

Comment: @SamJ.: "... to find the bootlicks." - I meant "bottlenecks", don't know what happened there :-)

Comment: @MartinR: Thanks! My problem turned out to be the fact that I was searching each new item in the list of all articles separately (even though I was doing it in a bg thread), I figured that out when I still saw the UI freeze after removing all the Core Data related code from my above example. Implementing a fetch request with an IN predicate, and sorting (when the feed finishes parsing. i.e. only once) is what finally got rid of the UI freeze. Thanks a bunch for the Find-or-Create Efficiently link!!

Answer (score 1):

The UI freeze is probably caused by `[self.managedObjectContext save:&error]` since writing out all the objects to disk takes a couple seconds. A great solution to this in iOS 5+ are nested contexts. See this blog post for more details http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/ in particular the Asynchronous Saving section at the end.

Comment: Just a warning about nested contexts.  I wasted a lot of time trying to work around their many bugs.  This post sums up lots of the issues, I had others as well.  I don't think they are ready yet.  http://wbyoung.tumblr.com/post/27851725562/core-data-growing-pains